# Splitting a dataframe according to a sequence

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 ... V8030
2  4  5  4  16  ...   2  
.
.
.
```

with ncol=8030. For each row I would like to group every column with the ones I get adding 365 to the column index.

So far I have been splitting the data frame in a list containing the values for each row

```
list    <- split(df, rep(1:nrow(df), each = ncol(df)))
```

but then I don't know how to proceed.

Many thanks

Comment: I mean for each row I want to average the values corresponding to the columns that I get adding 365 to the column index. So I want to get 22 value for each row

Comment: Relevant: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you need to do here is use `split.default` instead of `split`, as the `data.frame` method for `split` will split by rows instead of columns.  The following algorithm will produce a data frame where each column is the average of the (`n, n + m, n + 2 * m + ... + k * m`) etc. columns, where in you case `m` is 365, `k` is 22, and `n` belongs to `1:365`.

```
df.split <- split.default(df, rep(1:m, ncol(df) / m))
as.data.frame(lapply(df.split, apply, 1, mean, na.rm=T))
```

This assumes your data frame has a multiple of `m` columns.  In your case `m` is 365, and your data frame does have a multiple of those.  And here is some data I made up to test it:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- 5 # 365 in your case
k <- 3 # 22 in your case (8030 / 365)
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(k * m, sample(1:100, 10), simplify=F))
names(df) <- paste0("V", 1:(k * m))
df[[1]][[5]] <- NA
```

Comment: Hi, what instead if I have NA values in every row? In that case I don't want to include them in the average. Many thanks

Comment: @user3036416, see edits.  Also, please note that I was averaging 1-m, (m+1)-2m, (2m+1)-3m, which would have produced a result of 22 columns instead of the 365 you expect.  That is fixed.  Also, by using `na.rm` and `mean`, now NA values will be excluded from the means (so if you have one NA value in your row for columns 1, 366, 731, etc., the mean will be calculated on 21 values instead of 22).